# Rails Assets Pipeline load JavaScript from controllers and methods

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to stay DRY in my code so I want to auto-load my javascripts file when it matches a controller or/and a method and the `.js` exists. I added this to my layout

```
= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if ::Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.js")
= javascript_include_tag "#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}" if ::Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}.js")
```

So now when I add `javascripts/my_controller/my_method.js` it automatically loads it, which's nice.

Sadly I must add another line to precompile the asset otherwise an error is thrown (which says I must precompile my `.js` file) and I didn't find any way around this.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( orders/checkout.js )
```

Does anyone has a solution to avoid tu add manually elements in this configuration ?

***NOTE : I already tried to use `require_tree .` which was just loading all the files on every page and was not working in my case.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wildcard to allow all JS files included in your views to be precompiled:

`config.assets.precompile << '*.js'`

Comment: You just made my day ;)